# Silverlight 3 DataForm best practices

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-3.0, dataform

I have got a new project I am doing in Silverlight 3 which is a LOB application. It will have a fair number of data entry screens, some of which will be pretty complicated. Is the new DataForm control up to the task for anything other than simple generic forms or should I create custom forms? And if I create custom forms, are there any best practices available for layout out forms in XAML?

Answer (score 2):

I was messing around with Silverlight's DataForm control. The more complicated my forms got and the more customizations I needed to make, the more useless the DataForm became.

I have an article about developing Silverlight 3 applications on www.codeproject.com

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/Ag3DemoLOB.aspx